# Regex to find React JSX element with a given property?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, jsx

I'm doing an audit in a large codebase, and I need to search to find all uses of a component where it is used with a given prop. I'm thinking a regex could be useful here, but I can't figure out how to handle potential newlines in the markup. I need to be able to differentiate between these two usages, finding the latter:

```
<Component
  prop1="value1"
  prop2={2}
/>
```

```
<Component
  prop1="value1"
  targetProp={3}
  prop2={2}
/>
```

I don't care about the value of the target prop, just that it exists on the component.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```js
<Component(\s|\n)[^>]*?property
```

This one support line break.

Comment: Agreed, your solution is better! Thanks!

Comment: What if my component looks like this: `<Component icon={<Icon />} property={1} />` - the regex fails because of the inner `<Icon />`! Can you create a regex to support that as well? :)

Comment: The given solution unfortunately breaks if it meets a `>` in another Component's property:
arrow functions <Component onClick={()=>{}} property={1} />
and components as props <Component icon={<Icon />} property={1} />

Does anyone know if it's possible to enhance the RegExp to keep track of those?

Comment: <Field(\n.+)+property

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regex that should work:

`<Component\s[^>]*?targetProp={[^>]*?\/>`

This matches:

- `<Component` literally, with a `\s` whitespace character to avoid capturing `<ComponentWithALongerName`
- `[^>]` any character that's *not* `>`, zero or more times, lazily
- `targetProp={` literally (adjust if needed for boolean/string values)
- `[^>]` any character that's *not* `>`, zero or more times, lazily
- `\/>` literally

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not working when you have component as prop or arrow function (because arrow function has `>` character)

for example

```
<Component icon={<Icon />} property={() => ()} />
```

**Use this pattern instead**

`<Component((?:=>|<[^>]*>|[^>])*)>(.|\n)*$`

There is group in regex that I explain `(?:=>|<[^>]*>|[^>])*`

1. `=>` If its arrow function we match `=>` and allow `>`
2. `<[^>]*>` If there is another component in props, we allow `>` only if we have `<`.
3. `[^>]` In the end we accept any character unless its `>`