# RegExp to find React Components with specific properties on them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find a perfect RegExp to find React components with specific properties on them. The RegExp has to be used in the search field of my IDE VSCode.

Component example: `<Button>`

Property example: `size`

### Component on a single line

In case the opening tag of the component is on **one single line**, the RegExp I found that works perfectly is this (flags are not allowed in VSCode):

`/<Button.+size/`

For example this will be matched until the end of `size`:

```js
<Button onClick={()=>{}} size='medium'>
```

### Component on multi-line

Sometimes the component has so many props that the company code style would want it to split it on several lines, 1 property per line, like this:

```js
<Button
    type="button"
    size="tiny"
    className={styles.pauseButton}
    onClick={togglePaused}
    title="Pause or enable automatic loading of webhook requests in the debug console."
>
```

I can't manage to write a RegExp to match these particular cases:

1. Is there a single RegExp working for both cases (and not matching anything else)?
2. In case one single RegExp doesn't exists for both cases, is there a RegExp to match only multi-line components with a specific prop in between its opening/closing bracket?

### What I've tried

I've tried with `/<Button[\s\S]*?size[\s\S]*?>/` but it overmatches cases where there is a  without a size property, so it will keep matching until it find a size word somewhere.

At the moment I'm using `/<Button[\n]/` which matches ALL and ONLY the split components, and then I have to manual check if they have the specific property on them. I'd still prefer a RegExp that match the split with the specific property only.

I also found this [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012048/regex-to-find-react-jsx-element-with-a-given-property) too, but it breaks if the components has other properties that have a `>` inside, like arrow functions and components as props. This could be a good base to start from tho. The RegExp answered is:
`<Component(\s|\n)[^>]*?property`

Probably it's something with *lookaheads*, but I'm not experienced enough...

Thanks

Comment: You might try something like `<Button\b[^<>\r]*(?:(?<==)>[^<>\r]*)*size=[^<>]*(?:(?<==)>[^<>\r]*)*>` but this will break when there are other `<` `>` inside https://regex101.com/r/VnLed8/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird impressive! It actually solves the arrow functions problem and works pretty well.
What about a component prop like `<Button
    type={<Icon />}
    size="tiny"
    className={styles.pauseButton}
    onClick={togglePaused}
    title="Pause or enable automatic loading of webhook requests in the debug console."
>`

I can't figure out how to differentiate that > with the one actually closing the <Button> component. The only thing is that we meet another opening <, so that will mean that I'm gonna match not the first > but the second >, but it's a bit hard to put in RegExp.

Comment: That is why it is very hard to do that, see this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454

Answer (score 4):

For anyone having the same issue and want a quick fix here is a RegExp I found that works for multi line. I used this on a react code.

```
<Button[ \w=\{\}>\(\)\n;".-:]* size
```

I used this to find any Button component with the size property, its not perfect but got the work done for me.

Comment: This regex has some issues in components rendered like this due to the arrow function:


`<Input onClear={() => { onChange?.(""); }} ref={ref} />`


You can check the debugger on regex101
https://regex101.com/r/ilZvoQ/1

Answer (score 1):

The other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76651729/2809729 is almost correct except that it may get stuck if the optional chaining operator `?` gets used.

So this one improves on the other:

```
<Component[ \w=\{\}>\(\)\n;?".-:]*prop
```

That appears to be working also in subtle situations, like when you have a prop containing an arrow function using the `?`

```
<Component
 value="lol"
 onChange={ onChange?.(""); }}
 prop={"test"}
/>
```